# VTOR usage in ARM M3

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m

I am wondering that on a ARM M3 based MCU, what is the benefit of using VTOR register to relocate vector table? The reasons to my understanding is:

1. The vector table needs to be changed at runtime, and the default address (0x0 is readonly)
2. Reading from SRAM (say it is relocated to the beginning of SRAM region)is probably faster than the flash region?

Does that mean if all the interrupt handler is defined and known during compilation time, there is no need to use VTOR at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many reasons. However I think there are probably three main reasons.

1. You are using a bootloader, which would be based at 0x00000000. When the bootloader has finished doing its stuff it jumps to the application. The application would likely want to have its own vector table so the bootloader can set the address before starting the app.
2. You want a RAM based vector table so that you can install different handlers at runtime.
3. The application might load from some external ROM into RAM before running.

Comment: "You want a RAM based vector table so that you can install different handlers at runtime." Err... what about reset and hardware error interrupts? Placing the vector table in RAM doesn't sound like a brilliant idea.

Comment: Obviously you need to ensure that you have the important system vectors correctly setup in the RAM table. Nothing wrong with it in my opinion.

Comment: It is a bad idea because you will need 2 vector tables instead of 1. Out of reset you need to to use the flash-based vector table, and then you have to revert to the RAM based one after starting up... if you know at that point which RAM-based one you had picked previously. It sounds better and safer to use a custom function call from inside the NVM ISRs. Such a function call could be inlined.

Comment: I entirely depends on you application. If you need the best performance possible and runtime configurable vectors then the ability to directly install vectors will give improved performance. I am not saying that you should always do this, just pointing out it is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is clearer now as a lot of vendors provided their own bootstrap and the application simply wants to have a different table without touching the vendor specific ones.

Answer (score 2):

Every time when ARM M3 has reset, by default it takes value from address 0x00000000 and put it to SP register and value from address 0x00000004 to PC. This is start point for bootcode execution.
This happens because VTOR register is by default set to 0 and vector table start address are set at 0x0000000.

Bootcode checks if there is demand from  UART to start with boot code receive new firmware. If there is demand, bootcode receive byte by byte and program FLASH memory with this data received from UART port.

After this job is done, bootcode change VTOR register to 0x08001000 and jump to address 0x0001000 where is new vector table start address. This is start user code

```
void main()
```

This feature with programmable VTOR for Cortex M are excellent and simplified boot code procedure and code. Usually microprocessor/microcontroller has fixed address for vector value.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of such features is bootloaders. For example while a bootloader is programming the flash where the user-defined vector table is located, the MCU will have to use a vector table located elsewhere in the meantime.

Comment: hmm this is an interesting point...but does that mean the SRAM region is always powered on so the vector table is available to be fetched? What if retention is not supported and the table got wiped during restart?

Comment: On a standard microcontroller the internal RAM will normally be powered whenever the microcontroller is powered. That said it is probably more likely the applications vector table is located somewhere in the same flash ROM (in a different page with the application)

Comment: @Jackie.You'd have two vector tables in flash, at different addresses. Microcontrollers usually make no guarantee about RAM data integrity after reset, although in theory it is likely intact. Unless of course the reset source was the low-voltage detect. So having a vector table in RAM mostly boils down to nonsense, unless you can copy it from flash at start-up.